# Deleting library in .idea/libraries folder

Tags: android

I have faced problem in gradle folder and successfully solved it by adding this line

```
compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:26.0.1'
```

but in .idea/libraries folder in project folder I found two different version of the same library if I delete the older one ,is it cause a problem?

Screenshot of idea/libraries folder

[image]

Comment: Is your doubt answered?

Comment: I am not talking about deleting folder ,I said that inside this folder (ProjectFolder/.idea/libraries) there are two similar libraries with different version I asked what I happen if I deleted the library with version 23.2.1 which is customtabs_23_2_1 check the screebshot for more clarification and thanks for your response

Comment: Yes, if you can delete the folder then of course you can also delete anything inside it.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the folder without issue; it will be automatically regenerated by the IDE.

Comment: When is it regenerated? How can I force regenerate this folder?

Comment: Two ways to do this after deleting the `.idea/libraries` directory are:

1. Close project, then reopen project (is there a way to do this with one command?).
2. For Gradle projects: Sync project with Gradle files.

Comment: BTW: I have to do the sync with Gradle files twice for the libraries directory to be regenerated.